# Delete a Feature from a Different Version While Editing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, versioning, arcfm

We have one feature class that always loads from the default version (named 'Work Request'), even when you are editing inside a different version.  We use this feature class to identify areas where work in ongoing and we pull it from default so it doesn't get outdated when it displays while working in a version.

My question is: Is there a way to delete features from Work Request while editing in a different version (that isn't default)?

Here's a screenshot showing the version I am editing inside of (DN_1857) and the 'Work Request' feature class that is from Default:

[image]

The problem I am trying to solve is that it's part of my job to open a version, verify that it's correct, then reconcile and post it to default.  However, this process does not delete the work request feature that was identifying the work that I've now completed and posted.  So I have to start a new editing session just to delete the single polygon.  I would like to be able to delete that polygon while I have the version open and save myself the extra steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Work Request feature class is part of ArcFM - specifically ArcFM Designer which uses Workflow Manager (Telvent/Schneider-Electric WFM, not ESRI WFM).
How Work Requests are created & deleted is configured in the ArcFM Process Framework Administration Tool. There are tasks here that can be assigned & configured to allow you to delete a Work Request from within WFM.
You should not directly delete Work Requests outside of the ArcFM Workflow Manager. There is related data in multiple ArcFM WMS tables & you could end up with corrupt data.